# Xamarin - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I have many error (71) in my new project (Android - Xamarin).
I created new project and add my last layouts and xmls
When I tried to build this application it show me 71 error about drawable.

> No resource found that matches the given name (at...

[image]

I sent this project to my friend, he built and debug and it doesn't have error.
What should I do with this problem?